# Using jQuery event on ajax html response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm want to use jcarousel on an ajax html response.  Here is how i use jcarousel on elements loaded with the DOM.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel-2').jcarousel({ wrap: 'circular' });
});
```

Now when i use ajax, the above code doesn't work on the returned html.  What do i have to do to refire the jcarousel script?

```
var data = {
    action: 'get_thumbnails',
    id: id
};

jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
});
```

Comment: You just need to call it again within the callback function, setting the selector to match the element(s) you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call it inside ajax success callback to initate `jcarousel` again for dynamically loaded element

```
 jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
     //success callback
     jQuery('#mycarousel-2').jcarousel({wrap:'circular'});
 });
```

Comment: what about if the code is a script like `jcarousel.js`? i also have a similar dilemma.

Comment: In such case, my recommendation is to  wrap this code inside a function and call that function. eg: `function jCarousel(){ jQuery('#mycarousel-2').jcarousel({wrap:'circular'}); }` and call `jCarousel()` inside success callback. Make sure you laod the script file first

Comment: yes, do i have to reload the script file, if so how?

Comment: No.. you don't have to.. it should work if it is loaded already

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the proper approach, but you may use [jQuery's event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), I think it can be useful, if not in a straight way, then a tricky way :)

Answer (score -1):

Hey buddy i believe that the right code for ajax is this

```
$.ajax(
{
type: "POST",    /// your URL 
url: pageurl + "/testajaxfunc1",  /// backend function
data: '{"testval":"' + $('#testField').val() + '"}',  /// data fields
contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8", // content type
dataType: "json", // datatype
success: OnSuccessReturnValues, // function that it would initiate on success
error: OnError // function that it would initiate on Error
}
);
```

hope this help